# Unable to use autocomplete for combobox Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to include Autocomplete in my combobox but it's not working. Received an error when I'm trying to use tkentrycomplete. Below is the code I'm using for combobox, please point out my mistakes and help me out. Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd


comboExample1 = ttk.Combobox(window, width=30, values=list(df3["MFG Device"].unique()))
# comboExample1.current(0)
val = tk.StringVar()
comboExample1 = tkentrycomplete.AutocompleteCombobox(textvariable=val)
comboExample1.place(x=90, y=70)   
comboExample1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", select_device)
```

Error:

```
comboExample1 = tkentrycomplete.AutocompleteCombobox(textvariable=val)
NameError: name 'tkentrycomplete' is not define
```

Comment: se the variable first val.set("selection1 name")

Comment: what's selection1 name?

Comment: What is `tkentrycomplete`? it is not defined and that is why you have an errror.

Comment: included. my main purpose is to add autocomplete in the combobox :)

Comment: Have you tried the [ttkwidgets](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkwidgets) module? It has an `AutocompleteCombobox`: https://ttkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/autocomplete/AutocompleteCombobox.html

Comment: its your combobox string name

Answer (score -1):

tkentrycomplete is not a thing, I think what you need to do is `comboExample1.AutocompleteCombobox(textvariable=val)`

(I put this as an answer since I don't have enough rep to comment)

Edit:

try this:

```
comboExample1['values'] = val
```

(you may need to put this into a function and then bind it)

Comment: tried this and got an error.
AttributeError: 'Combobox' object has no attribute 'AutocompleteCombobox'